# Powershell: idiomatic way of mutating items passing through a stream?

Tags: powershell

When processing an input stream it's sometimes necessary to effect changes on the objects passing through the stream.  It's also useful to allow those objects to pass out the other end so that they may be piped into other processes.  Is there a more idiomatic/concise way than this to mutate and pass along?

```powershell
$input | % {
    if ($_.Office.length -ne 11) { $_.Errors += "Bad office" }
    $_ #needed to allow additional piping
}
```

Some other operator?  Something like... `%!`

```powershell
$input | %! {
    if ($_.Office.length -ne 11) { $_.Errors += "Bad office" }
} #whatever goes in must come out
```

Comment: I have found that using [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) preferrable to mutation.  One can effect mutation by recomputing a property based on its former state.  Bear in mind that each piped SELECT effectively copies the former object rather than mutate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the first example there, but you could write your own function and then use that:

```powershell
function Do-Modification {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline=$true
    )]
    $myObject
)

    Process {
        if ($myObject.Office.length -ne 11) {
            $myObject.Errors += "Bad Office"
        }
        $myObject
    }
}

$inputs | Do-Modification

# or to use it in a larger ForEach-Object (even though it's redundant here)

$inputs | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Do-Modification
}
```

#### Edit to add:

This is a contrived example; it's probably not worth it to reinvent the wheel (writing your own pipeline function) except for code re-use (where it is very much worth it in my opinion). It's up to you to decide where one approach or the other makes sense.